# .select/.first ruby methods - What is actually happening?

Tags: ruby

I have the following line of code:

```
name_array = ["Business", "Business", "Business"]
date_array = ["12/1/10", "1/1/11", "2/1/11"]
score_array = ["40","67","46"]

array = name_array.zip(date_array, score_array).select { |x| x.first == 'Business' }
```

What is the above line of code actually doing? I don't understand the `x.first` piece coupled with setting it equal to a string - I thought it returned the first value/values of an array?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? You can clear theses doubts by looking at each method documentation by yourself.

Comment: Luigi, when you have a question like this it is often helpful to look at parts of the expression in irb.  First look at `name_array.zip(date_array, score_array)`.  Now compare that to `name_array.zip(date_array).zip(score_array)` and `name_array.zip(*arr)` where `arr = [date_array, score_array])`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree with you.. I don't think SO should welcome this kind of question..There are ton of materials to find out the answers of this questions...No need to re-ask here..

Comment: @Pritti. I'm not complaining about the question, just offering a suggestion (which I couldn't have done if the question had not been asked).  The question also brought some solutions that depend on hash order and some that do not, which may be helpful to both Luigi and others.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. The tips are appreciated, and although I did read through documentation I did not try it in IRB. Certainly a weakness in my debugging skills, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is what [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) has done here.

```
# The .zip() call on its own:
name_array.zip(date_array, score_array)
# Returns a 2D array
# [["Business", "12/1/10", "40"], ["Business", "1/1/11", "67"], ["Business", "2/1/11", "46"]]
```

The result of `.zip` was a trio of sub-arrays, the first element of which is the value from `name_array`.

Then [`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-select) is applied to that 2-dimensional array.  `.select` takes a block as its argument. If that block returns `true`, the array value is returned.

So, it returns any sub-array (since it iterated over the 2D array) whose first element is `'Business'`. In your case, that's *all of them*.  Naturally, the `Array#first` is returning the first element of each sub-array, and then comparing it to a string (`== 'Business')`

```
# Calling .select on the literal array returned by .zip()
[
  ["Business", "12/1/10", "40"],
  ["Business", "1/1/11", "67"],
  ["Business", "2/1/11", "46"]
].select { |x| x.first == 'Business' }

# The result is the same as the input, since all of them match 'Business'
# [["Business", "12/1/10", "40"], ["Business", "1/1/11", "67"], ["Business", "2/1/11", "46"]]
```

Change the values of some of those to something other than `'Business'` and the `.select` will not return them.

```
[
  ["Business", "12/1/10", "40"],
  ["Something", "1/1/11", "67"],
  ["Else", "2/1/11", "46"]
].select { |x| x.first == 'Business' }
# [["Business", "12/1/10", "40"]]
```

Comment: While you are re-explaining the well documented things again, why not `String#==` ?

Answer (score 1):

The above line of code can be separated into several sections.

```
# Combine arrays elementwise
zipped_array = name_array.zip(date_array, score_array)
# => [["Business", "12/1/10", "40"], ["Business", "1/1/11", "67"], ["Business", "2/1/11", "46"]]

# Select all items where the first element is "Business"
zipped_array.select { |x| x.first == "Business" }
```

Here is the difference

[**Array#first**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-first)

> Returns the first element, or the first n elements, of the array. If the array is empty, the first form returns nil, and the second form returns an empty array. See also #last for the opposite effect.

Example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].first { |x| x > 3 }
# => 4

zipped_array.first { |x| x.first == "Business" }
# => ["Business", "12/1/10", "40"]
```

[**Array#select**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-select)

> Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for which the given block returns a true value.

Example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].select { |x| x > 3 }
# => [4, 5]

zipped_array.select { |x| x.first == "Business" }
# => [["Business", "12/1/10", "40"], ["Business", "1/1/11", "67"], ["Business", "2/1/11", "46"]]
```

**EDIT**

To specifically answer you question about `x.first`. `Array#first` without any block returns the first item in the array. There is also an `Array#last`

Example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].first
# => 1

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].last
# => 5
```